# Using wildcards to elegantly convert thousands of epub files to mobi

Tags: scripting, wildcards

I am executing the below command for 1000 files:

```
ebook-convert <name-of-first-file>.epub <name-of-first-file>.mobi
ebook-convert <name-of-second-file>.epub <name-of-second-file>.mobi
```

Apparently, instead of manually doing this for 1000 files, one could write a bash script for the job.

I was wondering if there is an easier way to do something like this in Linux though, a small command that would look something like

```
ebook-convert *.epub *.mobi
```

Can you use wildcards in a similar way, that works for a scenario like the above?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) clarify your operating system; do you mean Linux or Unix (Linux is _not_ Unix)? If Unix, what flavor? ii) change the example to show actual file names. Are the two commands you show somehow linked? Will you always need to run them in pairs? Or are they two independent commands (in which case Stephen's answer is what you need)?

Comment: In general, no, because the shell expands the quotes, so if you run `blah *.foo *.bar`, the shell just sees `blah a.foo b.foo x.bar y.bar`, it doesn't know they came from distinct wildcard entries on the original command line. And if nothing matching `*.bar` exists, well, depending on the settings, that pattern is left as-is, removed, or causes an error.

Comment: That's not using it "elegantly", that's using it like `copy` in MsDOS, ignoring the way glob patterns and the command line interface work in Unix. That's like insisting to use "gift" in English with its meaning from German.

Comment: "mobi" may be the *[Mobipocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats#Mobipocket)* format.

Comment: Why would you prefer mobi over opensource epub files?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can’t do it directly with wildcards, but a `for` loop can get you there:

```
for epub in ./*.epub; do ebook-convert "${epub}" "${epub%.epub}.mobi"; done
```

[Zsh supports a more elegant form of this loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669451/86440).

Instead of a shell script, if your file names don’t contain whitespace characters, and more generally can be safely handled by Make and the shell, you can use GNU Make; put this in a `Makefile`:

```
all: $(patsubst %.epub,%.mobi,$(wildcard *.epub))

%.mobi : %.epub
        ebook-convert ./$< ./$@
```

and then run `make`, which will ensure that all `.epub` files are converted to a `.mobi` file. You can run this repeatedly to update files as necessary — it will only build files which are missing or older than their source file. (Make sure that the `ebook-convert` line starts with a tab, not spaces.)

Comment: make doesn't get filenames with spaces right -- also your make example assumes GNU make syntax without mentioning it (pointlessly, as all that could be done with standard make inferrence rules like `.foo.bar:; whatever-convert $< $@`)

Comment: @ktzap thanks, I’ve added the caveats. I don’t think it’s possible to derive the `all` prerequisites in non-GNU Make, is it?

Comment: @ktzap, problems are not limited to whitespace, it's at least all the characters special in the sh (and likely also make) syntax. It's even a command injection vulnerability. Try with a `$(reboot).epub` file for instance (and of course, there's the usual problem with filenames starting with `-`).

Comment: @StephenKitt I vaguely remember there was a trick for that, but anyway, I think that a recursive make invocation would do: `all: *.epub; $(MAKE) $(?:.epub=.mobi)` --  `.SUFFIXES: .epub .mobi` -- `.epub.mobi:; ebook-convert $< $@`. (that's 3 separate lines; the POSIX standard makes no mention of globs in targets and prerequisites, but they used to work since the very first `make`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I wonder if `ninja` or whatever trendy make replacement has fixed that.

Answer (score 9):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
for f (./*.epub) ebook-convert $f $f:r.mobi
```

With `$f:r` expanding to the rootname (the part without the extension) of `$f` like in `csh`/`vim`...

Or:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -P ebook-convert './(*).epub' './$1.mobi`
```

(as `ebook-convert` doesn't seem to recognise the `--` option delimiter, we have to use a `./` prefix and use `-P` instead of `-p` to be able to cope with file names that start with `-`)

`zmv` is primarily intended for batch renaming, but also for batch copying/linking with `-C`/`-L` or can be extended to any form of change/conversion... by specifying the program to do it with `-p`/`-P`.

Or:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
alias ebc='noglob zmv -WP ebook-convert'
ebc ./*.epub ./*.mobi
```

With `-W`, `zmv` captures all wildcards on the source pattern, and converts all wildcard with incrementing `${1}`, `${2}`, etc in the replacement. So `zmv -W './*.epub' './*.mobi'` is the same as `zmv -W './(*).epub' './${1}.mobi'`. `noglob` disables globbing in the arguments to the command which avoids having to quote.

Or:

```
autoload -Uz zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs -I@ ./*.epub(:r) -- ebook-convert @.epub @.mobi
```

`zargs` being `zsh`'s `xargs`-like command to batch-process lists of arguments. `./*.epub(:r)` gets you the rootnames of the `.epub` files, and with `-I@`, `zargs` runs the `ebook-convert` command line with each `@` replaced with each of those rootnames in turn.

If your `ebook-convert` command accepted being called as `ebook-convert file1.epub file1.mobi file2.epub file2.mobi ...`, you could also do:

```
ebook-convert ./*.epub(e['reply=($REPLY $REPLY:r.mobi)'])
```

With that glob expanding to `./file1.epub` `./file1.mobi` `./file2.epub` `./file2.mobi`... thanks to the `e`val glob qualifier that runs the provided code for each matching file, where setting `$reply` defines the list of arguments the glob should expand to.

Or:

```
(){epub-convert $^@.{epub,mobi};} ./*.epub(:r)
```

Where we pass the list of rootnames of `.epub` files to an anonymous functions that uses brace expansion to pass arguments with both `.epub` and `.mobi` appended.

In all of those, to restrict the `*.epub` glob expansion to those which do not already have a newer corresponding `.mobi` file, you can add that `e['[[ ! $REPLY:r.mobi -nt $REPLY ]]']` glob qualifier, or add the check as part of the loop:

```
for epub (./*.epub) {
  mobi=$epub:r.mobi
  [[ $mobi -nt $epub ]] || ebook-convert $epub $mobi
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Can you use wildcards in a similar way, that works for a scenario like the above?**

Not like `ebook-convert *epub *mobi`, because of how wildcards - really "shell globbing" - works. But, you can get started with a wildcard.

Shell globbing is, conceptually, very straightforward: find all of the files that match the glob and replace the glob with that file list, handling whitespace and other "special" characters so that the invoked action (often a program; here, `ebook-convert`) gets each file as a single, separate parameter.

So, given a folder with `a.epub`, `b.epub`, and `file with spaces.epub`, the shell will expand `*.epub` to `a.epub`, `b.epub`, and `file with spaces.epub` as 3 separate arguments to whatever is being invoked (here, `ebook-convert`).

Given that same folder, `*.mobi` won't match anything, so `ebook-convert` will receive an argument that is literally `*.mobi`. From `ebook-convert`'s perspective, it's being given a list of three epub files and one mobi file that doesn't exist; how it handles that list of parameters is up to it (at a guess, it'll either complain about too many parameters or will sequentially try to convert each of the epubs into a mobi file literally named "*.mobi").

Note that there's no global guarantee about how a program (or shell built-in or function or script, etc.) will handle a parameter that it expects to be a file name but that contains a glob. Typically, that parameter will be treated as a string literal, and will react to `*.mobi` not existing just like it would to `anything_else.mobi` not existing, but there's no law that states that that has to happen.

The same thing happens for other globs; eg., `?.epub` would include `a.epub` and `b.epub`, but not `file with spaces.epub`.

As others have noted, you *can* use globs to power loops - `for file in *.epub ; do ...`. Note that references to "file" need to be quoted to handle spaces: the globbing in `for file in *.epub` only ensures that `file with spaces.epub` is a single parameter to the `for` loop itself, but doesn't extend into the body of the loop (that is, `for file in *.epub ; do ebook-convert $file` will send three separate parameters for `file with spaces.epub`: `file`, `with`, and `spaces.epub`).

All of this is also why you often need to quote arguments to programs that expect glob characters: doing so prevents the shell from expanding the glob and actually lets the invoked program see the argument as you wrote it. For example, `find . -type f -name '*.epub'` will find (and print the names of) all epub files in this directory and any child directories; `find . -type f -name *.epub` will error out since it'll see `b.epub` and `file with spaces.epub` as arguments with which it doesn't know what to do.

Comment: Note that the splitting of `file with spaces.epub` into `file`, `with`, `spaces.epub` upon unquoted `$file` doesn't apply to `zsh`. And in other Bourne-like shells, that's assuming `$IFS` contains the space character (and none of the other characters in`$file`). In those shells, globbing is also performed upon parameter expansion, not just IFS-splitting. rc/zsh/es/fish shells don't have that misfeature.

Answer (score 3):

using bash...

```
find . -name '*.epub' | xargs  basename -s .epub | xargs -I {} ebook-convert {}.epub {}.mobi ;
```

or, for filenames with spaces...

```
find . -name '*.epub' -print0 | xargs -0 basename -s .epub | xargs -I {} ebook-convert "{}.epub" "{}.mobi" ;
```

breaking it down...

```
find . -name '*.epub'

find . -name '*.epub' | xargs  basename -s .epub 

CMD='echo ebook-convert' && find . -name '*.epub' | xargs basename -s .epub | xargs -I {} $CMD "{}.epub" "{}.mobi" ;
```

the `-print0` and `-0` options cause those commands to use nulls instead of spaces to separate filenames.

`-I` creates a placeholder `{}` that works by substitution.

Ps: although this is a useful technique, I also think a Makefile (see above) is a great solution for this kind of task.

Comment: `find -print0` will output NUL-delimited records, but `xargs -0 basename` still outputs newline-delimited records, so you'll still have problems with filenames containing quotes or backslashes. While you're at using GNUisms, you could use `LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.epub' -exec basename -zs .epub {} + | xargs -r0I@ ebook-convert @.epub @.mobi`.

Comment: This is good.  I wondered if LC_ALL=C would be a problem with unicode characters, but it passed my test. (thing❦.epub)  Presumably the wide characters are processed as ASCII bytes and appear in the output unmodified.  Is that right?  Also, I think ```LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.epub' -execdir basename -zs .epub '{}' + | xargs -r0I@ ebook-convert @.epub @.mobi``` is more secure.

Comment: You need `LC_ALL=C` to handle file names that are encoded in the locale's charmap. Like a `$'Answer by St\xe9phane.epub'` (latin1 encoded) in a UTF-8 locale. In the C locale, every byte is a character so the `*` will match on any array of bytes, regardless of their representation as text.

Comment: `-execdir` won't help. `basename` doesn't try and access the files, so it makes no difference what its current working directory is. Using `-execdir` means at least one basename invocation for each dir with epubs. In any case, the approach only works for files in the current working directory, not subdirectories as `basename` strips the dirname part. You'd need to use something like `LC_ALL=C sed -z 's/\.epub$//'` to strip the extension without stripping the dirname.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do as cute as the `%.mobi: %.epub` from the GNU make part of the accepted answer --without GNU make and its filenames limitations-- with a little wrapper:

```
from_to(){
    sp=${1%%%*}; ss=${1#*%}; shift
    dp=${1%%%*}; ds=${1#*%}; shift
    for s in "$sp"*"$ss"; do
        d=${s#"$sp"}; d=$dp${d%"$ss"}$ds
        "$@" "$s" "$d" || exit 1
    done
}
```

Which you could use as

```
from_to %.epub %.mobi ebook-convert
from_to dir1/book_%.epub dir2/%.mobi ebook-convert
```

Mock test example:

```
% touch {1,2,3}.foo
% from_to ./%.foo bar/%.baz echo translate --
translate -- ./1.foo bar/1.baz
translate -- ./2.foo bar/2.baz
translate -- ./3.foo bar/3.baz
```

Anyways, you have to use something else that `*`, as that has a very established meaning in the Unix shell.

Comment: The point in using `make` is that it would not call `ebook-convert` on `file.epub` if a `file.mobi` existed and was newer than `file.epub`. See the part with `-nt` (also found in most `[`/`test` implementations even if not POSIX yet) in my answer.

Comment: Note that calibre's `ebook-convert` seems not to support `--` as end-of-option marker.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I've omitted `test -nt` because it's non-standard, and it's trivial to add if needed. Also, timestamps are not always reliable with this kind of stuff downloaded from the internet. But feel to add all that -- it's "community wiki"